# Cannot see files uploaded to Windows box running Apache

Tags: windows, apache, upload, tinymce, share

I have Apache set up on our development server (Windows 7 Home Premium). I am creating a CMS site and using TinyMCE to allow for the insertion of images. This all works fine, but I cannot access the images uploaded. I can see and edit them if I view them on the actual Windows box, but cannot view them over the network.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

- Alex

Comment: post your apache config, you should have Options Indexes defined for your Directory directive.

Comment: Hi - it's not that I can't see or access the files through the browser. I mean I can't see them in Windows Explorer. :(

Comment: look the apache logs then, something is going wrong with the upload

Comment: They are uploading fine. I can see them if I go to the box using VNC. it's just I cannot see them over the network share. I think it's because Apache is creating them and they have the wrong network permissions(?)

Comment: I found the solution to this: http://www.howyoudo.info/index.php/how-to-fix-windows-server-upload-file-inherit-permissions-error/